# Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [worker_id], Expected: LongType, Found: DOUBLE

Tags: python, pyspark, schema

I'm getting the error in the title.

when reading all the files all at once using the wildcard '*' with spark.read.parquet like this:
spark.read.parquet("/*.parquet", header = True, inferSchema = True)
and then when doing some operation over it (for ex, doing display), I get the error.

so instead I tried reading file by file and try and casting each corresponding df to long.
it's not an efficient solution but rather one that works.
is there any other way I can do it?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import os
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
input_directory = "<path>"
parquet_files = dbutils.fs.ls(input_directory) 

# Get a list of Parquet files in the input directory with the specified naming convention
# parquet_files = os.listdir(input_directory)
schema = spark.read.parquet(input_directory + "/<file_name>.parquet").schema

union_df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema)
union_df = union_df.withColumn("col1", col("col1").cast(LongType()))

# Process each Parquet file
for file in parquet_files:

    # Read the Parquet file with schema inference
    df = spark.read.parquet(file.path)

    # Perform schema casting to a common schema
    df = df.withColumn("col1", col("col1").cast(LongType()))

    # Union the casted DataFrame with the union_df
    union_df = union_df.union(df)

# Write the union of all processed DataFrames to a new Parquet file
# union_df.write.parquet(output_directory, mode="overwrite")

union_df.head()
```